# Storing HTML files

Tags: mysql, html, sql, filesystems, ext4

We have about 60 million webpages in a compressed format. We would like to de-compress and work with these files individually.

Here are my questions!

First, if I decompress them into the file system, would the FS cope with such number of files.  My file system is ext4. (I've 4 different file systems so I can divide the data between them like 15 M pages for each file system)

Secondly, Would storing these files into a relational database be a better option? assuming that all the hassle of cleaning html text is done before inserting them into the database.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extract them into a single directory you may exceed the maximum allocated indices in that folder. If you extract them into multiple directories you will fair better.

60 Million is definitely a fair amount, if you plan on doing any indexing on them or searching then a database would be your best option, you can do indexing on files using something like `lucene` it all depends on what you want to do with the files *After* they ave been extracted.

I currently have a similar issue with images on a large user site, the way I got around this issue was to give each image a GUID and for each byte in the guid assign it to a different directory, then the next byte under a subdirectory (down to 8 bytes) if my fill ratio goes up I'll create more subdirectories to compensate, it also means I can spread it across different net storage boxes.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is what I'm going to do. I will split it into different directories and hopefully it would work.